# Add blank page if current page is ODD in PHP mPDF

Tags: php, mpdf

I have table in HTML, which will take sometimes one page, sometimes more. After add this to pdf I need check how many pages I have so far and add blank page if I have an odd number of pages.
After that I will add another content.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

`$mpdf->page` holds the current page number, so you can use it to check what page you are on and add a pagebreak if needed:

```
if($mpdf->page % 2 == 1) {
    $mpdf->addPage();
}
```